# Self Referencing Variables in Pine Script for TradingView

Tags: pine-script, self-reference

so I was trying to convert this Absolute Strength histogram from pine script v2 to v4 and somehow it would not allow me to initialize and self reference a variable in the same line. How do I get around this?

This is the original code that I am trying to convert:

```
    calc_abssio( ) =>
        A=iff(close>close[1], nz(A[1])+(close/close[1])-1,nz(A[1]))
        M=iff(close==close[1], nz(M[1])+1.0/osl,nz(M[1]))
        D=iff(close<close[1], nz(D[1])+(close[1]/close)-1,nz(D[1]))
        iff (D+M/2==0, 1, 1-1/(1+(A+M/2)/(D+M/2)))

abssi=calc_abssio()
abssio = (abssi - ema(abssi,lma))
alp=2.0/(ld+1)
mt=alp*abssio+(1-alp)*nz(mt[1])
ut=alp*mt+(1-alp)*nz(ut[1])
```

This is my attempt at converting it to pine script version 4. The following code is not showing any information on the graph:

```
lma = input(19, title = "Ema Length")
ld = input(19, title = "Signal Length")
osl = 10


calc_abssio() => 
    A = 0.0
    M = 0.0
    D = 0.0
    A := close>close[1]? A[1]+(close/close[1])-1: A[1]
    M := close==close[1]? M[1]+1.0/osl: M[1]
    D := close<close[1]? D[1]+(close[1]/close)-1: D[1]
    iff (D+M/2==0, 1, 1-1/(1+(A+M/2)/(D+M/2)))

abssi=calc_abssio()
abssio = (abssi - ema(abssi,lma))
alp=2.0/(ld+1)
mt = 0.0
mt:=alp*abssio+(1-alp)*nz(mt[1])
ut = 0.0
ut:=alp*mt+(1-alp)*nz(ut[1])
s=((2-alp)*mt-ut)/(1-alp)
d=abssio-s
hline(0, title="ZeroLine")

plot(abssio, color=(abssio > 0 ? abssio >= s ? color.green : color.orange : abssio <=s ? color.red 
:color.orange), title="ABSSIO", linewidth=2, style = plot.style_histogram)

plot(abssio, color=color.black,title="ABSSIO_Points", linewidth=2)
plot(s, color=color.gray, title="MA")
plot(d, color=d>0?color.green:color.red)

stopLong = crossover(s, abssio)
stopShort = crossover(abssio,s)
plotshape(stopLong, style = shape.xcross, location = location.top, color = color.green)

plotshape(stopShort, style = shape.xcross, location = location.top, color = color.red)
```

Answer (score 0):

`nz` function with 1 argument would return 0 if recursive variable didn't existed on the previous bar :

```
calc_abssio() => 
    A = 0.0
    M = 0.0
    D = 0.0
    A := close > close[1]  ? nz(A[1]) + (close / close[1]) - 1 : nz(A[1])
    M := close == close[1] ? nz(M[1]) + 1.0 / osl              : nz(M[1])
    D := close < close[1]  ? nz(D[1]) + (close[1] / close) - 1 : nz(D[1])
    iff (D+M/2==0, 1, 1-1/(1+(A+M/2)/(D+M/2)))
```